# Comparing between two rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way I can compare between two rows in pandas?

I would do something like this in sql.

```
Select * from table t1, table t2 where t1.price - t2.price > 10 and t1.type = 'abc' and t2.type = 'def'
```

The best way i can think of is subtracting rows in pandas Data-Frame based on this:

```
abc = df[df['type'] == 'abc'] 
def = df[df['type'] == 'def']
```

And i am stuck as to how to go about doing this?

Something like

```
price     type 

10        abc
10        def 
30        abc 
15        def
```

It should return rows

```
10        def 
30        abc 
15        def
```

Comment: Can you add sample date with desired output? Thanks.

Comment: i am a bit confuse `t1` and `t2` are different tables? If yes, why are not in sample?

Comment: I should have mentioned t1 and t2 are the same table

Comment: When you compare the prices, are you comparing the price of the row just before it, or the row just before that also matches type, or some other row?

Comment: Every single row that satisfy the sql statement

Comment: But you're saying `t1.price - t2.price` - are there two columns of prices or just one column and multiple rows where `t1` and `t2` represent different rows?  Your data just shows one price column.

Comment: Yes one price column. T1 and t2 are the same table. I cannot use 2 t in sql but they refer to the same table

Comment: So back to my previous question - if you have a long list of prices, and are making a comparison between just two of them, which two do you want to compare?

Comment: More of every row that have a price difference of more than 10 when their types are different

Answer (score 0):

Aceminer, I'm still not totally clear what you're looking for on the comparison, but I set something similar up.  The one caveat here is that this code compares one line to the following so that the last line you have doesn't show up since there is nothing to compare it to.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':[10,10,30,15], 'type':['abc','def','abc','def']})

   price type
0     10  abc
1     10  def
2     30  abc
3     15  def
```

Filter:

```
df = df[(df['type'] != df['type'].shift(-1)) & (abs(df['price'] - df['price'].shift(-1)) > 10)]
```

Results in:

```
   price type
1     10  def
2     30  abc
```

Comment: Consider a single row and I want to find out which row in this data frame has a price greater than 10 difference and not of the same type against other rows in the df. Repeat this for all the rows in the df

Comment: Is the "single row" from outside of the existing dataframe?

Comment: No. Within the same frame

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't help.  I'm not sure which single row you're comparing against all other rows.

Comment: Maybe single row is not a correct word. But any row. Would it make a difference?